# Why my main.scss could not import other files

Tags: css, sass

I am having a problem in importing scss file.

I created a file, named, `main.scss` and write some code there.

All codes are working fine and reflecting the webpage.

then I created two folders, settings, and elements.

In settings, I created a file named, _colors.scss and defined some colors variable.

In elements, I created a file, named, `_typography.scss` and defined some code.

Now I wanted to import them into `main.scss`

but they couldn't import. I don't know why. Kindly help me.

Here is my final code.

`/src/css/main.scss`:

```css
@import "elements/typography";

@import "settings/colors";
```

`/src/css/elements/_typography.scss`:

```
a {   
    line-height: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: $primary-colour;
    word-break: break-all;
    word-break: break-word;
    &:visited {
        border-bottom: 1px solid;
    }
    &:hover {   
        border-bottom: none;
    }
    &:active {   
        color: $primary-colour;      
    }
    &:focus {   
        border: none; 
    }
}
```

`/src/css/settings/_colors.scss`:

```
$primary-colour: rgb(32, 221, 174);
```

Comment: Can you post the compiler output? Probably just the order of the import statements. Definitions used in typography must be loaded first.

Answer (score 2):

Your path is incorrect. Try this:

```
/src/css/main.scss

@import "./settings/_colors";
@import "./elements/_typography";
```

Also note that `@import "./settings/_colors";` goes first. Because you need your `$primary-colour` inside `@import "./elements/_typography";`

Comment: The paths aren't incorrect. `main.scss` is in the `css` directory with the `elements` and `settings` directories. You also don't need the underscore for imports of partials. However, you are correct in the order.